# Fastest way of sorting text file by sample identifiers

Tags: bash, sorting, awk, sed, bisection

I need to sort the file, **mwe.txt**:

```
>gb|LOEQ01000001.1|
1   CC|1    CC|1    NN|0    NN|0    NN|0    CC|1    NN|0    CC|1    CC|1    CC|1
2   AA|1    AA|1    NN|0    NN|0    NN|0    AA|1    NN|0    AA|1    AA|1    AA|1
>gb|LOEQ01000181.1|
1   CC|1    CC|1    NN|0    NN|0    NN|0    CC|1    NN|0    CC|1    CC|1    CC|1
>gb|LOEQ01000131.1|
1   CC|1    CC|1    NN|0    NN|0    NN|0    CC|1    NN|0    CC|1    CC|1    CC|1
2   AA|1    AA|1    NN|0    NN|0    NN|0    AA|1    NN|0    AA|1    AA|1    AA|1
3   AA|1    AA|1    NN|0    NN|0    NN|0    AA|1    NN|0    AA|1    AA|1    AA|1
```

by the sample identifiers in **names.txt**:

```
LOEQ01000001.1
LOEQ01000131.1
LOEQ01000181.1
```

I've been able to achieve this with sed and awk:

```
for f in $(cat names.txt); do sed -n -e "/$f|/,/>/ p" mwe.txt | awk '/>/&&c++>0 {next} 1' >> sorted.txt; done
```

Which results in:

```
>gb|LOEQ01000001.1|
1   CC|1    CC|1    NN|0    NN|0    NN|0    CC|1    NN|0    CC|1    CC|1    CC|1
2   AA|1    AA|1    NN|0    NN|0    NN|0    AA|1    NN|0    AA|1    AA|1    AA|1
>gb|LOEQ01000131.1|
1   CC|1    CC|1    NN|0    NN|0    NN|0    CC|1    NN|0    CC|1    CC|1    CC|1
2   AA|1    AA|1    NN|0    NN|0    NN|0    AA|1    NN|0    AA|1    AA|1    AA|1
3   AA|1    AA|1    NN|0    NN|0    NN|0    AA|1    NN|0    AA|1    AA|1    AA|1
>gb|LOEQ01000181.1|
1   CC|1    CC|1    NN|0    NN|0    NN|0    CC|1    NN|0    CC|1    CC|1    CC|1
```

The actual files I'm using are >120gb and my solution is really inefficient. I imagine it's possible to use a recursive merge sorting algorithm, but I'm not sure how to organise the input data so it can be sorted, mainly because of the inconsistent number of rows for each sample/identifier. Can anyone suggest a faster way?

Answer (score 4):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="|" }
NR==FNR { keys[++numKeys] = $0; next }
/^>/ { key = $2 }
{ block[key] = block[key] $0 ORS }
END {
    for (keyNr=1; keyNr<=numKeys; keyNr++) {
        key = keys[keyNr]
        printf "%s", block[key]
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk names.txt mwe.txt
>gb|LOEQ01000001.1|
1   CC|1    CC|1    NN|0    NN|0    NN|0    CC|1    NN|0    CC|1    CC|1    CC|1
2   AA|1    AA|1    NN|0    NN|0    NN|0    AA|1    NN|0    AA|1    AA|1    AA|1
>gb|LOEQ01000131.1|
1   CC|1    CC|1    NN|0    NN|0    NN|0    CC|1    NN|0    CC|1    CC|1    CC|1
2   AA|1    AA|1    NN|0    NN|0    NN|0    AA|1    NN|0    AA|1    AA|1    AA|1
3   AA|1    AA|1    NN|0    NN|0    NN|0    AA|1    NN|0    AA|1    AA|1    AA|1
>gb|LOEQ01000181.1|
1   CC|1    CC|1    NN|0    NN|0    NN|0    CC|1    NN|0    CC|1    CC|1    CC|1
```

That will be faster but it does mean you need to store the whole file in memory so try it and see if that's an issue. If it is then you could take a subset of key names at a time and use something like this script instead:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="|" }
NR==FNR { keys[++numKeys] = $0; tgtKeys[$0]; next }
/^>/ { key = $2 }
key in tgtKeys { block[key] = block[key] $0 ORS }
END {
    for (keyNr=1; keyNr<=numKeys; keyNr++) {
        key = keys[keyNr]
        printf "%s", block[key]
    }
}

< names.txt xargs -n 1000 echo | awk -f tst.awk - mwe.txt
```

which will print the line from mwe.txt 1000 at a time.

Comment: Excellent code, could you please explain it little here, will be grateful to you sir.

Comment: I think memory is an issue for mwe.txt, but not names.txt. With the original sed/awk script I usually have output within the first hour. Both of these solutions work on mwe.txt, but on the real data (120gb) they haven't yet produced any output for the first hour or so of run time.

Comment: I suspect you've copy/pasted incorrectly then. Try it on smaller files with less than 10 entries to see if that produces output. In any case - does every key value from names.txt exist in mwe.txt or just a subset of them? If it's all of them as shown in the example you provided then it doesn't matter but if it's subset then definitely use the 2nd awk script with your full input files as it'll only store the subset of mwe.txt corresponding to the keys in names.txt instead of storing the whole of mwe.txt like the first one does.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I suspect you can figure it out if you just think about it line by line as it's pretty basic so please do that and then let me know if you still have any questions and I'll be happy to answer them.

Comment: The command to run the second script should preserve the newline delimiter for xargs in order to run correctly with: `< names.txt xargs -n 1000 -d\n echo | awk -f tst.awk - mwe.txt >> output.txt`. I'm not sure why, but neither of these scripts output anything for the full dataset after waiting about 1 hour, even when I reduce the number of names being searched at a given time (for the second script). Both scripts work with smaller files. Perhaps I should note that each sample/entry can be tens of thousands of lines long...

Comment: add some debugging print statements like `/^>/ { key = $2; print NR, ++cnt, key |"cat>&2" }` so you can see exactly where it's getting stuck.